# DefaultIfEmpty() + select new MyStronglyTypeObj()

Tags: c#, linq

my aim is to return result via `left join` by `linq`. The `io.IsDefault` can be `null` but insted of this I want to return `MyStronglyTypeObj` obj with the rest data.

`context.Image.Where(i => i.IsActive == true)` have 3 rows. one of those have isDefault `null` because this `ImageId`- `(io => io.ImageId == i.ImageId)` dosent exist in `ImageObject`

```
var test2 = (from i in context.Image.Where(i => i.IsActive == true)
             from io in ImageObject.Where(io => io.ImageId == i.ImageId).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new MyStronglyTypeObj() { Alt = i.Alt, Caption = i.Caption, DisplayName = i.DisplayName, Extension = i.Extension, IsDefault = io.IsDefault, Height = i.Height, Width = i.Width, Name = i.Name });
        // return 2 imgs - the 3rd one without isDefault (isDefault = null) wasn't added to collection.
var test = (from i in context.Image.Where(i => i.IsActive == true)
            from io in ImageObject.Where(io => io.ImageId == i.ImageId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select i); // return 3 imgs
```

Is something obvious to me that I don't see? - perhaps I totally misunderstood the `.DefaultIfEmpty()` function

please help

Answer (score 0):

[`DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.7.2) only affects empty collections, and causes that collection to return a single element with value `default(T)` (where `T` == collection type).

For example, using strings (note `default(string)` == `null`):

[image]

So based on the code you provided:

- `DefaultIfEmpty()` is not a factor
- The only other difference is the `select` statement, which doesn't really make sense

I'm guessing `i` is type `MyStronglyTypeObj` (based on properties matching)? I suspect there's another factor when you're running this code that you're not taking into account.

Try putting a breakpoint on that line, and viewing the results in the debugger.

Also, because LINQ uses deferred execution, this query code doesn't actually "run" until it gets consumed, and depending on when that happens, the source data can change (essentially, easily causing timing bugs if you're changing the source data somewhere else). Even more frustrating, this can cause this bug to disappear when you use a debugger and view the results in that, as it causes the code to execute sooner. You can avoid this by adding a `.ToList()` at the end of the line to cause the results to be executed immediately.

Comment: you can also pass an explicit default value